# SML Match Redundant Error

Tags: sml, smlnj, redundancy

Im writing some code for an insertion sort in SML. Here it is.

```
fun compare(x:real, y:real, F) = F(x, y);
fun isEqual(x:real, y:real) = ((x <= y) andalso (x >= y));

fun rinsert(x: real, L: real list, F) = [x]
    |rinsert(x, (y::ys), F) =
    if isEqual(x, y) then rinsert (x, ys, F)
    else if compare(x, y, F) then x::y::ys
            else y::(rinsert (x, ys, F));

fun rinsort(L : real list, F) = []
    |rinsort(x::xs, F) = rinsert(x, (rinsort (xs, F), F);
```

For whatever reason i keep coming up with this error

```
- val compare = fn : real * real * (real * real -> 'a) -> 'a                                                                                                                                          
val isEqual = fn : real * real -> bool                                                                                                                                                                
stdIn:4.6-8.42 Error: match redundant                                                                                                                                                                 
          (x,L,F) => ...                                                                                                                                                                              
    -->   (x,y :: ys,F) => ...
```

I understand what it's saying, that I've got a repetitive line somewhere, but I'm not sure where the problem could be.

Answer (score 3):

The first line of `rinsert` has plain variables for each argument, so matches everything. Consequently, the second case is never reached. Same for `rinsort`.

To fix this, you'll need to replace the `L` parameter in both with the pattern `[]` for the empty list.